# jquery change immediate parent attribute from script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a jquery newbie

If I have a fieldset like this, how can I add new attributes like class="error" and also modify the text of the legend from the script?

I do not know anything about the fieldset or the legend apart from the fact that they exist

```
<fieldSet>
    <legend>My Legend</legend>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //I want to select the legend???
    </script>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: If there are multiple legends or fieldsets in you page how can we know which one to be changed? Will there be only one fieldset in your entire page?

Comment: That is why i want to select the most immediate one from this script element

Comment: Its bad practice to do this (though possible, maybe using document.write). If you can add a class or id or other attribute who identifies the fieldset or legend, it is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists workaround for this one.

```
<fieldSet>
    <legend>My Legend 1</legend>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var to = 'New Legend 1';
        var id = "temp" + Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
        document.write('<span id="'+id+'"></span>');
        var temp = $('#'+id); scriptParent = temp.parent(); temp.remove();
        scriptParent.find('legend').html(to);
    </script>
</fieldset>
<fieldSet>
    <legend>My Legend 2</legend>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var to = 'New Legend 2';
        var id = "temp" + Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
        document.write('<span id="'+id+'"></span>');
        var temp = $('#'+id); scriptParent = temp.parent(); temp.remove();
        scriptParent.find('legend').html(to);
    </script>
</fieldset>
```

All `SCRIPT` elements are evaluated in order as the document is loaded. So, when you use `document.write` inside inline `SCRIPT` element, the write accours right next to `SCRIPT`. Generating unique element after script, and referencing it, could be traced by DOM with ease. You can eaven try creating function for such an action. Just play with it, and I hope, you will understand :)

Answer (score 1):

To add the class:

```
$('fieldset').addClass('error');
```

To modify the legend text:

```
$('fieldset legend').html('New Legend');
```

However you need know more information about the fieldset, if you have more then on the page, because the code above will modify all the fieldset tags on it.

Comment: Will this not modify all legends on ths page?

Comment: All legends inside fieldsets.

Comment: To identify the fieldset you can add some class or id to it.

Answer (score 1):

From your example above the following would change the text of the 'legend' element and add a class to it -

```
$("fieldSet legend").text('New Text').addClass('newClass')
```

You might need to change the `$("fieldSet legend")` part of the code depending on what other elements you ultimately display on your page.

**EDIT**

If you want to refer to a specific fieldset you could do something like this to change the first fieldset on the page -

```
$("body fieldSet:first-child legend").text('New Text').addClass('newClass')
```

Otherwise you'd need to add a class or id to the fieldset. So if your fieldset looked like this -

```
<fieldSet class="chosen">
```

Your jQuery would need to be -

```
$("fieldSet.chosen legend").text('New Text').addClass('newClass')
```

Or if you add an id -

```
<fieldSet id="chosen">
```

jQuery -

```
 $("#chosen").text('New Text').addClass('newClass')
```

Comment: Will this not modify all legends on ths page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following expression?

```
$("legend").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQAPI](http://jqapi.com) for jQuery references if you are new to jQuery.